# Error in the output file of a for loops in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to perform a resample of a list using the for loops in R for generating a data frame that records the output of each trial.

I get the for loops to work without error, but I am sure I am making a mistake somewhere as I should not be getting the result for the jth entry that I get as possible outcomes.

Here's how I am generating my list:

```
set1=rep(0,237)  # repeat 0's 237 times 
set2=rep(1,33) # repeats 1s 33 times
aa=c(set1,set2) # put the two lists together
table(aa) # just a test count to make sure I have it set up right
```

Now I want to take a random sample set of size j out of aa and record how many 0's and 1's I get each time I perform this task (let's say n number of trials).

Here's how I have set it up:

```
n=1000
j=27
output=matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=n)
for (i in 1:n){
    trial<-sample(aa,j,replace=F)
    counts=table(trial)
    output[,i]=counts
}
```

Checking the output,

```
  table(output[1,])
      # 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27 
         1   1   9  17  46 135 214 237 205 111  24 

  table(output[2,])
     # 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  27 
       111 205 237 214 135  46  17   9   1   1  24
```

I do not think I am getting the right answer from the distribution for the `j`th value (in this case 27) for either of the expected number of 0's or 1's (should be close to 0 as oppose to the high number it returns).

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only `0`s in `trial` `length(counts)==1` and the value gets recycled when you assign to `output`. Try this:

```
for (i in 1:n){  
  trial<-sample(aa,j,replace=F)
  trial <- factor(trial, levels=0:1)
  counts=table(trial)
  output[,i]=counts
}
```

Of course, you could more efficiently use `rhyper`:

```
table(rhyper(1000, table(aa)[1], table(aa)[2], 27))
```